# Find mediaPath after UIImagePicker and UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

I Have an image picker where I pick a movie (which can be edited).  I then grab a thumbnail using;

```
UIImage *tempImage = [moviePlayerThumb thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

This work fine and I can display the image in another method no problems.  I also store the video data to upload later;

```
[mediaDict setValue:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:mediaPath] forKey:@"data"];
```

This also works as once uploaded the file plays no problem from the server.

The last things I store are the URL and Path, however, when I come to put these in a player later I get stuck with the player saying "Loading" (plus spinny thing);

I think it is because the picker after editing stores the video in a temp directory which (when I come to play the file later) has been emptied.

The paths are like this;

```
file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/B26A085A-C471-4972-9070-5A3F8DC48449/tmp//trim.ttCbAg.MOV
```

I tried to make the picker store the videos permanently like this;

```
    NSString *mediaPath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

    NSURL *mediaURL=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (mediaPath))
    {
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (mediaPath, nil, nil, nil);
    }
```

I know this is working because my Photo Album is slowly filling up with edited versions of my video.  The problem is how do I find out the path of the file AFTER the UISaveVideo method?

The player logs this;

```
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
```

The player code looks like this (I have tried using the mediaPath and mediaURL);

```
    // Play the movie
    NSURL *tempMediaPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:images[indexPath.item][@"path"]];

    NSURL *tempMediaURL = images[indexPath.item][@"URL"];

    NSLog(@"Media Path, URL : %@, %@", tempMediaPath, tempMediaURL);

    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:tempMediaPath];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [moviePlayer play];
```

And the NSLog;

```
Media Path, URL : file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/B26A085A-C471-4972-9070-5A3F8DC48449/tmp//trim.ttCbAg.MOV, file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/B26A085A-C471-4972-9070-5A3F8DC48449/tmp//trim.ttCbAg.MOV
```

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Ohh and also I have this in the .h @property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same in another project and the following code works in both embedded mode as well as fullscreen:

```
_movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:self.movieURL];
_movieController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
_movieController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
_movieController.backgroundView.hidden = YES;
_movieController.contentURL = self.movieURL;
[_movieController prepareToPlay];
_movieController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
_movieController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
_movieController.shouldAutoplay=YES;
_movieController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[self.view addSubview:_movieController.view];
```

Comment: Yep figured it now in round about way, this code works great, however, figured out why mine did not work! While implementing your code and adding the @synthersize for _movieController I noted that my moviePlayer was not there, there was no error because (as you can see from my code) I define it again! Very kind thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can better move the file to a temporary file location you control:

```
NSString *tempFileName = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
NSURL *location = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()] URLByAppendingPathComponent:tempFileName];

[[NSFileManager new] moveItemAtURL:tempMovieURL toURL:location error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. This has worked in the sense that the movie is moved (and I like this version as the other way filled up the Photo Album).  The problem is when I go to play it it still says "Loading...".  I even do a test before I start to play with         UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum ([tempMediaURL path]) which comes back fine.  Have I set my player up right?

Comment: I worry about the line the play throws out (should the player be 0); Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)

Comment: @RecycledSteel: See my other answer a possible solution.

Comment: Voted this up too as is much nicer than the photo album becoming full of edited movies and pictures (if like me you do something with the edit and do not need it again).